# Is there a way to dynamically modify the concurrency of celery worker in Airflow?

Tags: celery, airflow

I am scheduling tasks with Airflow, and the executor is celery. My question is:

Some tasks cost a lot of CPU time, and some not, is there a way to dynamically modify the concurrency of celery worker according to the load of the server? 
For example, if the tasks now cost a lot of CPU and the server is in heavy load, the concurrency of the celery worker should shrink dynamically, otherwise the concurrency should grow.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think that is possible only when the worker is running in the autoscaling mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've haven't used `Airflow` with `CeleryExecutor`,

but a close-enough effect can be achieved (at least for `LocalExecutor`) by adding your `task`s to [`pool`s](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=pool) and [modifying those pools (`slot`s count) programmatically](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2c99ec624bd66e9fa38e9f0087d46ef4d7f05aec/airflow/api/common/experimental/pool.py#L45).

And I can confirm that dynamic modification of pool slots (when the Dag is running) works just fine.

*(not sure if it is risky / anti-pattern)*